# number of entries using blue card for my home country

Tags: germany, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian and I am blue card holder from Germany.

How many time I can go to my home country and return back to Germany per year using national visa?

And the blue card, is there any limits, could it be in monthly base?

Comment: Have you got your residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel) yet?